# servicemix 4.3.0 and jndi

Tags: jndi, apache-servicemix

I have servicemix 4.3.0 in my system and i want to connect to a database using this. I am a newbie with regard to servicemix and searched for how to achieve this integration. The forums suggested to edit the jndi.xml present in the conf directory of the servicemix installation. But my installation does not have a folder by the name "conf".

Does that mean my installtion is corrupted?
Is there any other way to achieve the db connectivity to MySQL?

Thanks,
Jisha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to create the jndi.xml file.  See [this forum](http://servicemix.396122.n5.nabble.com/JNDI-JDBC-DataSource-for-ServiceMix-4-td3371885.html) and [the servicemix documentation](http://servicemix.apache.org/old/jndi-configuration.html) for more details.